# Is there a reason that a film SLR would be preferred to a digital SLR?

Tags: dslr, digital-vs-film, slr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of photography is still better done with film cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-kind-of-photography-is-still-better-done-with-film-cameras)

The capabilities of digital photography continue improve, however some manufacturers (including [Nikon](http://www.nikon.co.in/en_IN/products.page?CategoryID=gp11zkyr)) still sell film SLRs.

Are there any advantages to film over digital?

Why would somebody still choose to pick up a film SLR over a digital SLR?

Comment: I marked a possible duplicate, but I notice the answers to that question are rather poor.

Comment: @mattdm this one for sure is a plain duplicate of the other one! :doh: but that one didn't result in the similar threads, when I created this question. Raising a bounty on that question when this one is currently running?